# Dropdown Menu Pushing Parent Menu Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have five parent menu items, and the third one has a child dropdown menu. When you click on the third parent menu, the dropdown menu shows up, but it pushes the fourth and fifth parents menu items to below.I'd like the dropdown menu to be below the parent menu row, without pushing any parent menu items. It's a Shopify site.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

http://jsfiddle.net/3s2qhhx3/

```js
//Main nav expanders
$(document).on('click', '#navpanel .mainnav .title', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(window).trigger('reup-navbar');
});
var navSpeed = 150;
$(document).on('click', '#navpanel .mainnav button', function() {
  //Prep animation on sublist
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('expanded')) {
    $(this).html('<span class="icon-plus"></span>');
    $(this).siblings('ul').stop(true, true).css('display', 'block').slideUp(navSpeed, 'linear', function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded');
      $(window).trigger('reup-navbar');
    });
  } else {
    $(this).html('<span class="icon-cross"></span>');
    $(this).siblings('ul').stop(true, true).css('display', 'none').slideDown(navSpeed, 'linear', function() {
      $(window).trigger('reup-navbar');
    });
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded');
  }
  $(window).trigger('reup-navbar');
});
$(document).on('click', '#navpanel .mainnav a[href="#"]', function() {
  $(this).siblings('button').trigger('click');
  return false;
});
```

```css
#navbar #navpanel .mainnav {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navbar #navpanel .mainnav > ul > .active > ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar #navpanel .mainnav li li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainnav">
  <ul class="tier1">
    <li id="blog">blog</li>
    <li class="">
      <a class="tier1title" href="/collections/newarrivals">New Arrivals</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a class="tier1title" href="/#">Categories</a>
      <ul class="tier2">
        <li class="">
          <a href="/collections/knits">Knits</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/collections/tops">Tops</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/collections/dresses">Dresses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/collections/bottoms">Bottoms</a>
        </li>
        . . .
        <li class="">
          <a class="tier1title" href="/collections/sale">Sale</a>
        </li>
        <li class="registerform">
          ...
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is javascript code?

Comment: @AlexChar Added. Thanks for looking at the post.

Comment: when post a question is better to post a fiddle to demonstrates the problem. That way more people will help you :)

Comment: Better post your fiddle.. ^^

Comment: @AlexChar Added a fiddle. I think sliding on click works through Shopify liquid code, so I couldn't add that to the fiddle. But I think it shows how the menu looks when the submenu is displayed, and that's what I'd like to change. So maybe it's still helpful...?

Comment: @user26409021 Added a fiddle. I think sliding on click works through Shopify liquid code, so I couldn't add that to the fiddle. But I think it shows how the menu looks when the submenu is displayed, and that's what I'd like to change. So maybe it's still helpful...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `position` of your sub-menu to `absolute`. Also, you need to change your first `<li>` display to `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

CSS:

```
.mainnav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainnav ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.mainnav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    background:red;
    height:auto; 
    width:auto; 
}
.mainnav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Hope it helps. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s2qhhx3/2/)..

Comment: Thanks! Why do I need to change the first li to inline-block?

Comment: When you only put `inline`, the next element will show up beside it. By changing it to `inline-block`, it will reserve the space beside it so that's why the next `ul` is showed up underneath `li`. Check out this [link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) for better understanding..